# SharePoint 2010 Incoming Emails

Tags: 2010, incoming-email, exchange-server

I have a SharePoint 2010 environment with 3 servers, one web front end, one app server and one database server.

Currently when users email the list I can see the email land in the drop folder for a brief few seconds before it is then processed by SharePoint and disappears.

The issue I have is that it then doesn't do anything however I then see the following in the Event Viewer:

> A critical error occurred while processing the incoming e-mail file C:\inetpub\mailroot\Drop\email_9121.eml. The error was: Bad senders or recipients..

I have given all of the accounts full control over the drop folder including the timer job account.

This is what I currently see in the header of the emails (edited our some personal details)

> Received: from NTE2K10MBX3.mydomain ([fe80::bc8a:b799:fe80:ed45]) by
>    NTE2K10CASHUB2.mydomain ([11.11.1.111]) with mapi id 11.11.111.111; Fri,
>    13 May 2016 15:29:09 +0200
>   From: "Bloggs, Joe" 
>   To: username 
>   Subject:
>    =?utf-8?B?UkU6IFRSLWFkbWluLmludHJhbmV0LTI2NjHCoC0gQXByb2JhY2nDs24gcmVx?=
>    =?utf-8?Q?uerida_[#DDDCFXDFXYNV#]?=
>   Thread-Topic:
>    =?utf-8?B?VFItYWRtaW4uaW50cmFuZXQtMjY2McKgLSBBcHJvYmFjacOzbiByZXF1ZXJp?=
>    =?utf-8?Q?da_[#DDDCFXDFXYNV#]?=
>   Thread-Index: AQHRrP009qQ0Zwm63UCvNocEezAWQZ+23NZg
>   Date: Fri, 13 May 2016 14:29:08 +0100
>   Message-ID:
>    <39AB8F5B71065A44BB2016508BB1CB60456FCC1B@NTE2K10MBX3.mydomain>
>   References:
>    <52293320-b0cb-4563-973a-45d24e7ab764@NTE2K10CASHUB1.mydomain>
>   In-Reply-To:
>    <52293320-b0cb-4563-973a-45d24e7ab764@NTE2K10CASHUB1.mydomain>
>   Accept-Language: en-GB, en-US
>   Content-Language: en-US
>   X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthAs: Internal
>   X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthMechanism: 04
>   X-MS-Exchange-Organization-AuthSource: NTE2K10CASHUB2.mydomain
>   X-MS-Has-Attach: yes
>   X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
>   X-MS-TNEF-Correlator:
>   Content-Type: multipart/related;
>       boundary="_004_39AB8F5B71065A44BB2016508BB1CB60456FCC1BNTE2K10MBX3plas_";
>       type="text/html"
>   MIME-Version: 1.0

We are currently using Exchange Server for our emails. I have also configured all of the incoming and outgoing settings in Central Administration.

I would appreciate any help anyone can give me with this.

Comment: Can you please provide the header of the EML? Stop the incoming mail service so the message does not disappear, open with notepad, and provide that here. Make sure to re-start the incoming email service to validate that this particular message encounters the same error.

Comment: Hi Trevor, please see my updated question for the header.

Comment: Your 'from' and 'to' aren't formatted as email addresses. How would SharePoint know how to route it?

Comment: Sorry they are in the actual header, I modified them, they actually show as From: "Bloggs, Joe" <Joe.Bloggs@mydomain.eu>
To: username <username@mydomain.eu>

Comment: @eric-alexander this question should not be closed. It is an Incoming Email question, regardless of the source.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, I have edited my question now. Thank you for your support on this! Much appreciated!

Comment: does 'username@mydomain.eu' exist as an email address within SharePoint assigned to Document Libraries or a Group? Remember that incoming email is only used for emailing Doc Libs or SharePoint Groups and not for any other objects, such as users.

Comment: The "To:" email is the reply-to-address I have set in the out going email settings in central administration, it is actually the name of the intranet application followed by the domain, for instance it is "intranet@mydomain.eu" however the account also actually has an inbox in Exchange that this is being picked up from. The original email has been sent to "intranet@mydomain.eu" then picked up from the inbox and has landed in the drop folder.